# MsWord APIs - How to shift content of table cell from one to another

Tags: c++, ms-word

I tried using `Cell->Copy()` and `Cell->Paste()` methods, but this also modifies the clipboard. Is there any other method to shift the whole content of one cell to another?

I have tried setting the `Cell->Range->Text` but that excludes the other objects like images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some C# code that demonstrates how to use the object model to transfer formatted content between table cells within a Word application instance (same document or different documents), *not* using the Clipboard.

This uses `Range` objects for both source and target cell. When a `Cell.Range` is assigned to an object variable it will contain *the entire cell*  - this includes the end-of-cell character(s) ANSI 13 + ANSI 7 that store the cell structures. In order to copy *only* the content, without the cell structures, these characters need to be trimmed from the `Range`. Depending on how the object model is used, one or two characters need to be trimmed.

Trimming is done for a `Range` by reducing the scope of the `Range` (think of it like holding the Shift key while pressing right-arrow for a selection) - here for the source `Range` using the method `MoveEnd`. In my tests for this code sample trimming one character worked, but you'll want to test it.

For the target `Range` the code sample uses the `Collapse` method to put the focus at the start of the target cell (think of it like pressing the Left-arrow key to collapse a selection to a blinking insertion point at the beginning of the selection).

Then it's simply a matter of setting the `FormattedText` property of the target `Range` to the `FormattedText` property of the source `Range`.

```
    Word.Table tbl = doc.Tables[1];
    Word.Range rngCellSource = tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range;
    Word.Range rngCellTarget = tbl.Cell(2, 1).Range;
    rngCellSource.MoveEnd(Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1);
    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(rngCellSource.Text);
    rngCellTarget.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart);
    rngCellTarget.FormattedText = rngCellSource.FormattedText;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see one in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.cell?view=word-pia).

The whole notion of "shifting" data is necessarily cutting it from where it is, and pasting it someplace else.

I'd question why you are afraid of touching the clipboard. This is its purpose.

Comment: This is a background process running in my application. I don't want the clipboard to get modified because while this is happening, user might actually be working on the clipboard.

Comment: @user3908730 I'm no expert but you'll probably find that Word was not really designed to be used this way, despite the layering on top of this API.